# A2070:invalid instruction operands on push ecx 32-bit register in 64-bit mode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm

I'm quite new to Assembly and I have a little problem.
I'm trying to work with loops, but when I tried to test my program I got error

> A2070:invalid instruction operands

on lines 15,17,19,22 (with push instruction)

```
extrn ExitProcess: PROC
extrn printf: PROC

.data
komunikat1 db 'This linecode should be shown as %d ,and 10th should be last.', 0

Start PROC
 push rdi
 sub rsp, 28h
 mov ecx, 1

_petla:
 inc ecx
 push ecx
 dec ecx
 push ecx
 push komunikat1
 call printf
 add esp,16
 pop ecx
 or   ecx, ecx
 jne  _petla

 call ExitProcess
Start ENDP
END
```

I don't even know if it's the only problem, as I said I just started with Assembly and I couldn't find and good materials to learn from on the Internet.

I'm working on MASM x64.

Comment: You appear to be trying to use the 32-bit calling convention. The 64-bit calling convention [is different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention). Try googling _"windows 64-bit nasm printf"_ or something along those lines.

Comment: You say you are using NASM but your code looks like MASM.

Answer (score 1):

In Nasm x64 the stack is 64 bit wide.

So you can't push ecx register.

The operand must be 64 bit in size.

Use

```
push rcx
```

instead if

```
push ecx
```

Comment: Yes, the only size of push you'd *want* to use is 64-bit, and 32-bit is impossible, but the machine does allow 16-bit push/pop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 64bit registers like rcx with the PUSH instruction in x64 bit processor.

```
PUSH rcx
```